# Problema con html y css

Tags: html, css

todo bien ? .. la cuestión es la siguiente, pues estoy aprendiendo html y css por mi cuenta, totalmente autodidacta, leyendo en foros, internet, youtbe, etc.. la cuestion es que estoy practicando haciendo mi primera web, pero tengo un problema...

Ahora mi pregunta es, yo tengo el header fijo, para cuando se haga scroll el header se mantenga, pero para la Class video, popular, entradas y amigos cuando hago scroll esos se sobreponen encima del header, yo quiero que se oculten detras del header como me sucede con la class primera y segunda.

Algun comentario de como arreglar eso o porque me esta sucediendo? Gracias

PD: Les recuerdo que soy totalmente inexperto, es mi primera pagina y todo esto lo he hecho aprendiendo solo, por aquello de que encuentren muchos errores o demás..saludos

---

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: solid;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
.verde {
    color: green;
}
.azul {
    color: blue;
}
.rojo {
    color: red;
}
.eslogan {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-decoration: underline;
    
    
}
header {
    background-image: url(fondo.jpg);
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;

}

img {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
}
.calvo {
        position: absolute;
        right: 150px;
        top: 0px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(fondo2.png);
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  

}
a {
    color:darkblue;
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-decoration: none;
   
}
li:hover a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(135, 189, 236, 0.917);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(96, 111, 186, 0.5);
    border: solid black;
   
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    
}

.primera {
    border:  groove;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;   
    background-image: url(madera.jpg);

    
}
.segunda {
  border:  groove;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px; 
    background-image: url(madera.jpg); 
  
}

/*codigo del video youtube*/
.video {
    border:  groove;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 90px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url(madera1.jpg);
  
  
    
   
    
}
.mira {
    color: rgba(243, 241, 116, 0.958);
}

/* primer cuadro popular post*/
.popular {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 250px;
    border:5px double rgb(166, 164, 18);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(onfire1.jpg);
    background-size: 100px;
   
  
    

    }
.post {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: oblique;
    color: rgb(121, 24, 24);
    text-decoration: underline;
  
}
.texto {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: brown;
    font-style: italic;
    
}
.linkentra {
    color:rgb(121, 91, 212);
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    

}
.texto1 {
    text-align: center;

}
.texto1:hover {
    
    background-color: rgba(184, 236, 135, 0.917);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}
.linkentra:hover {
    color: black;
}
/* segundo recuardro entradas nuevas*/
.entradas {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 500px;
    border:5px double rgb(166, 164, 18);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(new.jpg);
    background-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;

}
.nuevas {
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.linkentra {
    color:rgb(121, 91, 212);
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    

}
.texto2 {
    text-align: center;
    

}
.texto2:hover {
    
    background-color: rgba(184, 236, 135, 0.917);
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 180px;
}
.linkentra:hover {
    color: black;
}

/* tercer cuadro amigos*/
.blogs {
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 650px;
    border:5px double rgb(166, 164, 18);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: url(amigos.jpg);
    background-size: 95px;
   
    

    }

.linkentra {
    color:rgb(121, 91, 212);
    font-family: fantasy;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    

}
.texto3 {
    text-align: center;

}
.texto3:hover {
    
    background-color: rgba(184, 236, 135, 0.917);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}
.linkentra:hover {
    color: black;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;    
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    
}
.footer {
    margin-top: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog de Robby</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>

        
            <h1> <span class="verde">E</span><span class="azul">L</span> <span class="rojo">B</span><Span class="verde">L</Span><span class="azul">O</span><span class="rojo">G</span> <span class="verde">D</span><Span class="azul">E</Span> <span class="rojo">R</span><span class="verde">O</span><span class="azul">B</span><span class="rojo">B</span><span class="verde">Y</span></h1>
            <p class="eslogan">Disfruta tu estancia aquí<p>


        
                <div class="calvo"><img src="calvo.webp" alt=""> </div> 
                <div class="miblog"></div><img src="miblog.png" alt="">
            
            
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>


                </ul>
            </nav>
       
    </header>


    <main>

        <section class="primera">
            <h2>Mi primera entrada</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, quibusdam. Excepturi odio velit veniam non voluptate? Consequuntur sunt explicabo laborum voluptatem debitis dolorum, laboriosam quis omnis eligendi dolor mollitia, est iste rem cum quae corporis sit! Placeat, similique dolore.</p>
        </section>
           
    
        <section class="segunda">
            <h2>Mi segunda entrada</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, ad. Voluptatibus, accusamus asperiores quas cupiditate debitis officia unde quod necessitatibus ratione ducimus natus possimus labore officiis nisi ipsa repellat? Veritatis cupiditate harum enim quas consectetur rerum. Natus officia, praesentium sequi aliquam aut atque repudiandae, aperiam in omnis ratione ducimus fugit!</p>
        </section>

        <section class="video">
            <h2 class="mira">Mira mi video nuevo!!!</h2>
            <iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uUIuj4WTfWk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </section>
        
          

    </main>
    
    <aside>

    <section class="popular">

            <h2>Popular Post</h2>
            <p  class="texto">Post nuevos!!! <br><br>
            <p class="texto1"><a class="linkentra" href="#">Entra Aquí</a></p>
            
    </section>
         
    <section class="entradas">

            <h2 class="nuevas">Entradas Nuevas</h2>
            <p class="texto2"><a class="linkentra" href="#">Entra Aquí</a></p>
    </section>

    <section class="blogs">

            <h2 class="amigos">Blogs Amigos</h2>
            <p class="texto3"><a class="linkentra" href="#">Entra Aquí</a></p>
    </section>
         
        
     



  

      
    </aside>
   

    <footer> 
        <p class="pie">Derechos Reservados 2020 </p>
        <p class="footer">Cartago,Costa Rica</p>

       
    </footer>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si la respuesta de Juan García te ayudó a resolver el problema, no dejes de marcarla como respuesta aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probar lo siguiente:

```
header {
   ...
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index